# How can I maintain multiple versions of an applications on playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I want to maintain multiple versions of an application ,so that EMM admin has a control where he can silently push different version to different devices using android management api.

Google play doesn't allow to maintain multiple versions of an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean and what you want for different versions. There are a bunch of important questions:

- would you ever want a user to change version from one version to another (and back again)?
- would you ever want a user to have two versions installed at once?

If the answer to both of the above is yes, then you will need to use different package names for the versions. If the answer is no, then Google Play lets you have [different versions using test channels](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).

But in general you are right. Google Play requires all users of an app to get the latest version.

Comment: I have a scenario where we have to rollout an application to 1000 devices ,but before that we rollout a pilot build to 5-6 users and if everything goes right we rollout it to all the devices.
But if anything goes wrong we rollback pilot user to the older version.

I wouldn't prefer  changing the package as it would lead to change in lot of config settings , so is there any other way I can achieve this ?

Comment: You can either use closed testing tracks if you want a specific 5-6 users, or used staged rollouts https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149 if you want a percentage. Android (the OS) does not allow you to decrease the version code on an app. So to do a rollback, just rebuild the old version with a higher version code, and use that to rollback.